# Make parallel sectioning compatible with minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, minitoc

I use the new environment `SoftwareBreak`, created at [Creating independently-numbered Chapter-level structures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98137/creating-independently-numbered-chapter-level-structures/98294#98294).

Would you know how to make `minitoc` compatible with it ? One could tell `m`initoc to consider `\begin{SoftwareBreak}` as the beginning of a new chapter, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to add

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{\vskip -2.8em \@plus-\p@}{}{}}
\adjustmtc\minitoc%
```

to `SoftwareBreak`'s definition. So it becomes

```
\newenvironment{SoftwareBreak}[2][\SB@temp]
   {\gdef\SB@temp{#2}%
    \global\let\@chapapp@old=\@chapapp
    \global\let\thechapter@old=\thechapter
    \gdef\@chapapp{\SWbreakname}
    \gdef\thechapter{\theSWbreak}%
    \SB@chapt{#1}{#2}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{\vskip -2.8em \@plus-\p@}{}{}}
\adjustmtc\minitoc%
   }%
   {%
    \global\let\@chapapp=\@chapapp@old
    \global\let\thechapter=\thechapter@old}
```

Comment: You like the answer!?, ... so please have a look to https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ... thanks.